# How do you remedy iMac (2009) slow start-up, and sluggish performance?

Tags: imac, macos, memory, performance

here are my system details:

OS X El Capitan - gold

iMac (21.5-inch, Late 2009)
3.06 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo
12 GB 1067 MHz DDR3

I have reduced startup to 1 or 2 apps, have at least 75GB avail on 500GB hard drive. A few months back I upped RAM from 4gb to 12gb. I don't do anything super-intensive on the machine. With 12GB this baby should be humming along fine. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Ram is not not so useful for start-up, but for real-time applications instead. It may depends to something else. Did you try installing an SSD?

Comment: I have not tried that.